# Why __soapCall throws "Forbidden" whereas __doRequest suceeds?

Tags: php, soap

Let's consider the following SOAP client example below. It basically extends the PHP native one (note we are in `wsdl` mode):

```php
use SoapClient;
use SoapFault;

abstract class AbstractClient extends SoapClient
{
    abstract protected function getHeaders(): array;

    private function call(string $functionName, array $arguments)
    {
        $this->__setSoapHeaders(
            $this->getHeaders()
        );

        try {
            return $this->__soapCall($functionName, [$arguments]);
        } catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
            // ... 
        }
    }

    public function sendRequest(string $functionName, array $arguments)
    {
        return $this->call($functionName, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Requesting the SOAP server using `__soapCall` keeps throwing a `SoapFault`:

```
faultstring: Forbidden
faultcode: HTTP
```

I tried with diffentent configurations, changing cache, SOAP version, SSL stream context, etc., but still, to no avail.

Now, imagine requesting the same endpoint with `__doRequest`, passing the XML request generated with the previous implementation (XML was dump from `$this->__getLastRequest()` in the catch part), then it works and we get the expected response from the server.

From there, I overrode the `__doRequest` in the client (`__doRequest` is called by PHP at a lower level to perform the `__soapCall`) to see what were the differences:

```php
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
{
    // Output $request, $location, $action, $version and $one_way

    parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
```

It turns out the only one is the lack of param `$action` which was empty. So I hardcoded it, but again, to no avail: the Forbidden exception was thrown again.

Has anyone any idea on what's happening here?

**EDIT**

After many more tests, I can now tell that formatting the XML request (not into a single line but a "prettyfied" version of it) actually works. Maybe I'm missing some kind of encoding/formatting configuration, unfortunately the PHP doc is not very accurate on this subject...

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a dirty solution. Overriding `__doRequest` and formatting the request with `DOMDocument` do the trick:

```php
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->loadXML($request);
    $request = $xml->saveXML();

    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
```

Does anyone knows how to configure the PHP SOAP extension to achieve this properly?